# Choose wrapping view when layout is wider than screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal linear layout with an image and a couple text views. In some languages (German...) the text is so long that to fit everything on one line, the layout would have to be wider than the screen. To prevent this, android automatically makes the text views wrap on to the next line.

Is there any way to choose which of the text views will end up wrapping? At the moment it appears that the last view added to the layout is the one that wraps. However I'd really like to have one of the earlier text views wrap and have the last text view always display on a single line. Is this possible? I've already subclassed most of the views involved so I can override protected methods.

Heres a rough outline of my code:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/some_icon" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/can_wrap_if_neccessary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_really_long_text" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/shouldnt_wrap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some_more_really_long_text" />
</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: the solution is to set the layout_weight attribute on the view(s) that I want to wrap, and not set it at all on the views I don't want to wrap. Any view with a layout_weight will wrap in preference over those without.

Comment: How to know at run time which text will wrap? Because textview wrapping depends on screen width. What is the answer to your question "Is there any way to choose which of the text views will end up wrapping?

Comment: I don't need to know which view is going to wrap. I need to set which view is going to wrap. If I set a layout weight on a specific view, and I don't on other views, then the view with the weight (or the lower weight) will wrap before the views with no or higher weights.

Comment: I needed to add weight to both of my textviews in linear layout but add the percent of screen i wanted left one to wrap at as its weight and fill the rest with right textview

Answer (score 2):

We can know which Text will wrap.

**Logic:**
*First calculate width of Text If width of Text is greater than width of the screen, that text will be wrapped*

The following method returns true if text will be wrapped else returns false

**Source code**

```
boolean isTextWrapped(String text) {
        boolean isWrapped = false;
        int widthOfText = 0;
        int deviceWidth = 0;
        // calculate widthOftext
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        widthOfText = bounds.width();
        System.out.println("...text view width..."+widthOfText);
        // calculate width of screen
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        deviceWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        System.out.println("...text view width..."+widthOfText+"...screen width..."+deviceWidth);
        isWrapped = widthOfText > deviceWidth ? true : false;
        return isWrapped;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't what i meant to ask. I don't need to know which text view will wrap, but rather I want to specify which one wraps.